# Find and return a Node in Binary Tree Java

Tags: java, search, tree, binary-tree

Hi I'm trying to find a node equal to a string given by parametres and return that node. My structure is a binary tree of strings. We assume that the string searched exists.

The var q is inicializated to the root of the tree. (in the function I called the method find)

```
private NodeTree find(NodeTree q, String cont){
   if(q._contingut.equals(cont)) return q;
   else {
       if(q._left!=null) return find(q._left,cont);
       else if(q._right!=null)return find(q._right,cont);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: What's your issue ? -- edit : got it. Don't return find(q._left, cont). Because your algo is only getting through the "left nodes".

Comment: That it doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 4 of the find() function you shouldn't return the result of recursive call over left subtree. Instead you should search the right subtree for the string if you get "NULL" from the left subtree.

Here is the updated code

```
private NodeTree find(NodeTree q, String cont){
   if(q==NULL) return NULL;
   if(q._contingut.equals(cont)) return q;

   NodeTree result = NULL;
   if(!q._left) result = find(q._left,cont);
   if(!result && q._right) result = find(q._right,cont);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: !q._left? !result?

Answer (score 0):

If your BST is built correctly, you need to decide where to look (left or right subtree) comparing current node value to query value, something like:

```
NodeTree find(NodeTree q, String query) {
   if(q.value.equals(query)) 
       return q;
   else if (q.value.compareTo(query) > 0) 
       return q.left == null ? null : find(q.left, query);
   else
       return q.right == null ? null : find(q.right, query);
}
```